# Extracting an xml value in Groovy

Tags: groovy

I have this code

```
String dbresponse = '''
 <rows>
  <row>
    <file_data>One</file_data>
    <time_inserted>2019-01-30T10:29:20.543</time_inserted>
  </row>
  <row>
    <file_data>two</file_data>
    <time_inserted>2019-01-30T10:29:20.547</time_inserted>
  </row>
  <row>
    <file_data>three</file_data>
    <time_inserted>2019-01-30T10:29:20.550</time_inserted>
  </row>
  <row>
    <file_data>four</file_data>
    <time_inserted>2019-01-30T10:29:20.550</time_inserted>
  </row>
  <row>
    <file_data>five</file_data>
    <time_inserted>2019-01-30T10:29:20.553</time_inserted>
  </row>
 </rows>    
'''

def response = new XmlSlurper().parseText(dbresponse)
def data = response.rows.row[1].file_data
print data
```

I have two questions:

1] With the above code why am I not getting the response of: two ?
2] How do I iterate through the entire xml doc to get this response:
one
two
three
four
five

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1] With the above code why am I not getting the response of: two ?

As per the [Official Groovy doc](http://groovy-lang.org/processing-xml.html#_xmlparser_and_xmlslurper) it should be

```
def rows = new XmlSlurper().parseText(dbresponse)
println(rows.row[1].file_data)
```

First line is "parsing the XML an returning the root node as a GPathResult". In your case, the root node is `rows`

> 2] How do I iterate through the entire xml doc to get this response: one two three four five

```
println("Iterating using each() method")
rows.row.file_data.each { row ->
    println(row)
}

println("Iterating using Groovy for loop")
for (fileData in rows.row.file_data) {
    println(fileData)
}

println("Getting a list of necessary elements using Groovy Spread operator")
def fileDataList = rows.row*.file_data
println(fileDataList)
```

Output:

```
Iterating using each() method
One
two
three
four
five

Iterating using Groovy for loop
One
two
three
four
five

Getting a list of necessary elements using Groovy Spread operator
[One, two, three, four, five]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how it works:

```
def rows = new XmlSlurper().parseText(dbresponse)
print (rows.row[1])
print (rows.row[1].file_data)
```

The identifier, `rows`, gives a handle on the object returned when parsing `dbresponse` (`<rows>` in this case). I named it `rows` since this is the convention slurp'ers use; it doesn't have to be.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there, just trivial.

In the script you posted, it was trying to extract only first row data. That's why remaining data not shown.

Here is the script you can get all the data

```groovy
def response = new XmlSlurper().parseText(dbresponse)
def data = response.'**'.findAll{it.name() =='row'}*.file_data*.text()
println data
```

You can quickly try it online <kbd>[Demo](https://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/5165185417347072)</kbd>